# Send order email automatically

Tags: magento-1.9, orders, email, order-email

When a user buys something with PayPal, they receive an automatic email about the purchase, if someone does it by the default tpv, they don't receive a confirmation email, and I have to send it manually. Is there any way to send it automatically just as PayPal (when they order anything).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This should actually be working.

Can you check if your cron is set up correctly? In addition, check the `core_email_queue` table in the database. If you find entries of orders that have long since happened there, it's a sign that your cronjob does not work.